# Why is the word "that" used here?

Tags: grammar

> Why this strife of the chase? why weary, and palsy the arm at the oar, and the iron, and the lance? how the richer or better is Ahab now? Behold. Oh, Starbuck! is it not hard, that with this weary load I bear, one poor leg should have been snatched from under me? Here, brush this old hair aside; **it blinds me, that I seem to weep**. (from *Moby Dick* [Source](http://americanliterature.com/author/herman-melville/book/moby-dick-or-the-whale/chapter-132-the-symphony))

I'm having trouble understanding why the word *that* is used in the bolded part of this quote.

Answer (score 1):

Causation; this is equivalent to:

- it blinds me so that I seem to weep
- it blinds me, causing me to weep

Comment: It blinds me. As a result, it seems like I weep?

Comment: Literally: As a result, tears come from my eyes, which makes it look like I am crying.